# R subset function not removing observations

Tags: r

I have a very large RStudio dataset (dataset is called "loan") I'm using for econometrics and can't seem to remove rows according to column value.

[R dataset screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ITbK.png)

I'm trying to remove observations which have an "appinc" value of over 200.

I have tried the following code (and many other similar variations eg using loan$appinc) but it doesn't seem to remove any observations and I really do not know where I am going wrong.

appinc <- subset(loan,appinc > 200)

According to my tutors, 89 observations should be removed after eliminating rows with appinc over 200 (appinc > 200).

I would appreciate any help.

Thank you

Comment: Have you checked if "appinc" column is numeric?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Jonathan V. Solorzano is correct, is is likely that your appinc vector is a factor, but you are trying to apply an arithmetic operation on it, try:

```
appinc <- subset(loan, as.numeric(as.character(appinc)) > 200)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work. Is the column `appinc` numeric? Do you get any error messages?

Here is my sample code which gives me results as expected:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)

loan <- tibble(appinc = round(runif(1000, min=0, max=1000), digits = 0))

loan_filtered1 <- loan %>%
  filter(appinc > 200)

loan_filtered2 <- subset(loan, appinc > 200)
```

`loan_filtered1` uses the dplyr approach while `load_filtered2` uses the `baseR:subset` function.

Results:

```
> glimpse(loan_filtered1)
Observations: 801
Variables: 1
$ appinc <dbl> 664, 928, 750, 988, 874, 850, 587, 518, 590, 221, 421, 346, 588, 455, 285, 922, 571, 389, 768, 488, 599, 675, 423, 596, 901, 862, 499, 513, 977, 313, 5…

> glimpse(loan_filtered2)
Observations: 801
Variables: 1
$ appinc <dbl> 664, 928, 750, 988, 874, 850, 587, 518, 590, 221, 421, 346, 588, 455, 285, 922, 571, 389, 768, 488, 599, 675, 423, 596, 901, 862, 499, 513, 977, 313, 5…
```

Comment: loan <-loan[!(loan$appinc>200),] I used the following code and it seemed to work. thank you all. The appinc is numerical but I didn't receive any error messages